# Crash Inside UIAlertControllerAnimatedTransitioning

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I am getting crash reports from an exception being thrown in the following method:

```
-[_UIAlertControllerAnimatedTransitioning _animateTransition:completionBlock:]
```

It is occurring in `_UIAlertControllerTransitioning.m:146`

The only information included in the crash is:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0
```

The full call stack looks like this:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1b33bb38 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:165)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a5c3062 objc_exception_throw + 34 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1b33ba14 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 92 (NSException.m:131)
3   Foundation                      0x1bc31528 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 88 (NSException.m:157)
4   UIKit                           0x20b4a706 -[_UIAlertControllerAnimatedTransitioning _animateTransition:completionBlock:] + 700 (_UIAlertControllerTransitioning.m:146)
5   UIKit                           0x20b4a052 -[_UIAlertControllerAnimatedTransitioning animateTransition:] + 530 (_UIAlertControllerTransitioning.m:102)
6   UIKit                           0x208a0c3e __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 3342 (UIPresentationController.m:850)
7   UIKit                           0x207e697e _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 272 (UIApplication.m:2468)
8   UIKit                           0x207d9c8e _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 520 (UIApplication.m:2447)
9   UIKit                           0x2055b8b8 _afterCACommitHandler + 108 (UIApplication.m:2499)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x1b2f77fe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1802)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x1b2f5a50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 278 (CFRunLoop.c:1898)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x1b2f6012 __CFRunLoopRun + 1354 (CFRunLoop.c:2849)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1b2491aa CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 466 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x1b248fcc CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 (CFRunLoop.c:3143)
15  GraphicsServices                0x1c9f3b3c GSEventRunModal + 76 (GSEvent.c:2245)
16  UIKit                           0x205cba4e UIApplicationMain + 146 (UIApplication.m:4089)
17  OnBeat                          0x8fd9c main + 48 (AppDelegate.swift:15)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x1aa364e6 _dyld_process_info_notify_release + 26 (dyld_process_info_notify.cpp:327)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this post](https://medium.com/@onmyway133/xcode-8-and-uialertcontroller-87c4f599e21), the actual Exception description from the assert on that line of _UIAlertControllerTransitioning.m is:

> UIAlertController is expected to have a visual style during transitioning

There seems to be a couple reasons this might happen:

### 1. The Window you are trying to present an alert on is not configured with the correct size

Based on this [this post](https://medium.com/@onmyway133/xcode-8-and-uialertcontroller-87c4f599e21) make sure that you wait until `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` to create your window.

Instead of something like this in your app delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    // BAD DON'T DO THIS
    var window: UIWindow? = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
}
```

Make sure you create your window like this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    open func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        // Setup rootViewController and whatever other properties
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
   }
}
```

### 2. You are trying to present an alert on an external screen (through HDMI or Airplay)

I avoided this by first checking if the window of the view controller is the key window:

```
guard let window = self.view?.window else {
    print("Attempt to present alert on view controller without a window")
    return
}

guard window.isKeyWindow else {
    print("Attempt to present alert on window that is not the key window")
    return
}

// Present alert
```